# How to write a karma-jasmine test for the values inside an object attached in a function for a controller written in john papa stye

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is how my controller looks like:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('vmCtrl', vmCtrl);
  vmCtrl.$inject = ['$state', 'API', 'serviceConfig'];
  function vmCtrl($state, API, serviceConfig) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.formValues = {};
  vm.submitForm = function() {
  vm.formValues = {
        "name": vm.formValues.name,
        "age": "18",
        "schoolId": vm.formValues.schoolId,
        "mobno": "21234"
      };
  var url = serviceConfig.BASE_URL + 'details';
  API.post(url, vm.formValues)
    .then(submitForm_success)
    .catch(submitForm_error);
    }
   }
})();
```

the following specs in karma returned success on testing,

```
it('should define vmCtrl', function() {
  expect(vmCtrl).toBeDefined();
});

it('should define submitForm', function() {
  expect(vmCtrl.submitForm).toBeDefined();
});
```

Now is it possible to test the values inside the object formValues? Like if I need to test the age using .toEqual(18)

How should I write the spec for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the method first and then check the value.

```
it('should define submitForm', function () {
  vmCtrl.submitForm();
  expect(vmCtrl.formValues.age).toEqual(18);
  expect(vmCtrl.formValues.mobno).toEqual(21234);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, javascript doesn't really have any notion of private variables.  So you can write the following:

```
it('should initialize formValues.age', function () {
    expect(vmCtrl.formValues.age).toEqual(18);
});
```

Just be aware, that for that test to pass, you would first need to call `vmCtrl.submitForm()` and in order for that to work, you would need to properly mock `API.post()`